# Asana - How to query for tasks completed between dates?

Tags: ruby, asana-api

I am trying to get a collection of tasks that are in a specific team and completed between certain dates such as last month. I see in the API docs that there is a task.find_all but that seems to give everything after a certain completion date and then it even gives incomplete tasks.

From ruby-asana docs:

> .find_all(client, assignee: nil, workspace: nil, completed_since: nil, >modified_since: nil, per_page: 20, options: {}) ⇒ Object
>   Returns the compact task records for some filtered set of tasks.

From Asana API:

> completed_since '2012-02-22T02:06:58.158Z'
>   Only return tasks that are either incomplete or that have been completed since this time.

It seems like I would need to get tasks completed after a certain date and then iterate and select those that have a completion date before my end date and are completed.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delayed answer, but yes, that is currently the way to do it.